# How do you create reports that show the number of

Tags: reports, searchkit

We need to report on various demographics (gender, age, sexuality, ethnicity, etc...) and changes over time...

So far, I seem to only manage to produce lists of individuals / contacts that match each of the criteria, but how would I go about producing a report that answers these types of questions:

How many new BAME* joined our charity between 1st April and 30th June (*sorry, that's british for ethnic minority)

Or how many members identify as male, female, trans F, trans M, non-binary etc

I am panicking that this is not even possible within Civi...

I've tried creating groups, searches within groups, searches using advanced search and search builder, reports...

As mentioned in my first post, I am a complete newbie

thanks for any advice

Comment: What CMS are you using. TBH if this was me, and I was using Drupal, I would just whip them up via Views

Comment: also worth familiarising  yourself with SearchKit which is in more recent releases of CiviCRM

Comment: https://civicrm.org/blog/awestbha/using-search-kit-wild-0

Comment: Our Civi is hosted on Drupal - sounds I have to learn that on top of learning Civi.... I have read something about 'views' and will need to go learn in depth

Comment: also SearchKit... given the example shown below, looks like it could provide me with what I need. I am happy to then take into Excel for further complex manipulation - Thank you for info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's [an example](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22gender_id:label%22,%22COUNT(id)%20AS%20COUNT_id%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%22gender_id%22%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D) showing how you could get counts by gender using SearchKit on dmaster:

[image]

You probably want to add some 'Where' clauses to limit the counts to those of interest.

In general, 'changes over time' reports are harder because you need historic data and Civi primarily reflects the current state. One option is to record the current state over time and compare it outside of Civi.  Other approaches make use of logging to determine the state at a previous time - eg [this blog post.](https://civicrm.org/blog/agilewarejustinfreeman/how-many-members-did-we-have-date-how-many-times-has-member-renewed-how)

Comment: Thank you, this will work perfectly for me for the time being, and I am happy to work with more complex stuff in excel...